# Spacy Confidence Score in SpanCategorizer

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

I have trained a Spacy nlp model with a 'spancat' model.
For testing the model, I have added the code below for prediction of spans and label

```
nlp = spacy.load('output_/model-best')
rest = 'The book was of red colour'
doc1 = nlp(rest)
print(doc1.spans) #To get predicted span
span = doc1.spans['sc'][0] 
print(span.label_) # to get label
```

How can I also get the confidence score for prediction of the spans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the score directly from the span group, using the `scores` attribute. For example:

```
doc = nlp("your text here")
spans = doc.spans["sc"]
for span, confidence in zip(spans, spans.attrs["scores"]):
    print(span.label_, confidence)
```